# HTTP server can't be reached from Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: python, http, server, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

My Python server is reachable from a browser but not from a Raspberry Pi Pico.

Python server server.py:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import time
import httphandler
import itemtype

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 60001

class AirServer (httphandler.HttpHandler):

    AIR_TIME = 10 #* 60
    AIR_EARLY_START_HOUR = 9
    AIR_EARLY_END_HOUR = 16
    AIR_LATE_START_HOUR = 17 #19
    AIR_LATE_END_HOUR = 22
    MAX_HUMIDITY = 60

    request = None

    def delegate(self, command, params):
        if command.startswith("q"):
            command = "query"
            for param in params:
                if param.startswith("j"):
                    self.logJson = True
                elif param.startswith("v"):
                    self.logVerbose = True
                elif param.startswith("a"):
                    self.logAlertsOnly = True
        self.logStart(refresh=(command=="query" and "r" in params))
        if command != "query":
            if command.startswith("i"):
                command = "item"
            elif command.startswith("s"):
                command = "suppressalerts"
            else:
                self.logAlert("Unknown command: {}".format(command))
                return
        self.logCommand("Request: {}".format(self.path))
        if command == "query":
            self.delegateQuery(params)
        if command == "suppressalerts":
            self.delegateSuppressAlerts(params)
        elif command == "item":
            self.delegateItem(params)
        self.logFinish()

    def delegateQuery(self, params):
        for param in params:
            if param.startswith("j"):
                self.logJson = True
            elif param.startswith("v"):
                self.logVerbose = True
            elif param.startswith("a"):
                self.logAlertsOnly = True
        for id in AirServer.items.keys():
            item = AirServer.items.get(id)
            self.logHighlight(str(item))
            self.checkItem(item)
            if self.logVerbose:
                self.logSize = "small"
                for sample in item.samples:
                    self.log("\t{}".format(str(sample)))
                self.logSize = "medium"
        """if not self.logJson:
            for id in AirServer.items.keys():
                item = AirServer.items.get(id)
                self.logSize = "small"
                self.logLink("{}:{}/s/{}".format(AirServer.hostname, AirServer.port, id), "Suppress alerts for {}".format(id))
                self.logSize = "medium"
            for s in ("frueh", "spaet"):
                self.logSize = "small"
                self.logLink("{}:{}/s/{}".format(AirServer.hostname, AirServer.port, s), "Suppress alerts for {}".format(s))
                self.logSize = "medium"""

    def delegateSuppressAlerts(self, params):
        serverItem = AirServer.items.get("server")
        suppress = serverItem.getCurrent("suppress")
        if suppress is None:
            suppress = ""
        l = suppress.split("~")
        if params:
            l.extend(params)
        l_ = []
        for s in l:
            if len(s) > 0:
                l_.append(s)
        if l_:
            serverItem.addSample(["suppress", "~".join(l_)])

    def checkItem(self, item):
        if str(item.getCurrent("air")) == "1":
            # early air
            # late air
            # max air time
            openTimes = []
            t = None
            lastOpen = "0"
            for sample in item.samples:
                if sample.getCurrent("open") != lastOpen:
                    lastOpen = sample.getCurrent("open")
                    if lastOpen == "1":
                        t = sample.time
                    elif lastOpen == "0":
                        openTimes.append((t, sample.time - t))
            if lastOpen == "1":
                dt = time.time() - t
                if dt > self.AIR_TIME:
                    self.logAlert("{} {} offen fuer {}, muss geschlossen werden!".format(itemtype.fmtT(t), item.id, itemtype.fmtRT(dt), item.id))
                openTimes.append((t, dt))
            foundEarly = False
            foundLate = False
            for openTime in openTimes:
                if openTime[1] >= AirServer.AIR_TIME:
                    self.logHighlight("\t{} Lueftung fuer {}".format(itemtype.fmtT(openTime[0]), itemtype.fmtRT(openTime[1])))
                    hour = time.localtime(openTime[0]).tm_hour
                    if hour >= self.AIR_EARLY_START_HOUR and hour < self.AIR_EARLY_END_HOUR:
                        foundEarly = True
                    if hour >= self.AIR_LATE_START_HOUR and hour < self.AIR_LATE_END_HOUR:
                        foundLate = True
                else:
                    self.log("\t{} offen fuer {}".format(itemtype.fmtT(openTime[0]), itemtype.fmtRT(openTime[1])))
            hour = time.localtime().tm_hour
            if lastOpen != "1":
                if not foundEarly and hour >= self.AIR_EARLY_START_HOUR and hour < self.AIR_EARLY_END_HOUR:
                    self.logAlert("{} {} Noch keine fruehe Lueftung!".format(itemtype.fmtNow(), item.id))
                if not foundLate and hour >= self.AIR_LATE_START_HOUR and hour < self.AIR_LATE_END_HOUR:
                    self.logAlert("{} {} Noch keine spaete Lueftung!".format(itemtype.fmtNow(), item.id))
        humidity = item.getCurrent("humidity")
        if humidity is not None:
            humidity = int(humidity)
            if humidity > self.MAX_HUMIDITY:
                self.logAlert("{} {} Zu hohe Luftfeuchtigkeit, {}%!".format(itemtype.fmtNow(), item.id, humidity))

    def delegateItem(self, params):
        def usage():
            self.logAlert("Syntax error, usage: /item/id/key1/value1/key2/value2/...")
        if len(params) < 1:
            usage()
            return
        id = str(params[0])
        pairs = params[1:]
        if len(pairs) % 2 != 0:
            usage()
            return
        item = AirServer.items.get(id)
        if item.addSample(pairs):
            self.log(str(item))
        else:
            self.logAlert("Malformed sample")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    AirServer.start_(AirServer, hostname=HOST, port=PORT)
```

HTTP handler httphandler.py:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import itemtype

class HttpHandler (BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    items = None

    DEFAULT_LOG_COLOR = "#bbb"
    ALERT_LOG_COLOR = "#f88"
    REFRESH_RATE = 2 #10

    logJson = None
    logVerbose = None
    logAlertsOnly = None
    logColor = None
    logSize = None
    logAlerts = None

    def header(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()

    def do_HEAD(self):
        self.header()

    def do_GET(self):
        print("do_GET(): ")
        self.header()
        self.logInit()
        self.parse(self.path)

    def do_POST(self):
        print("do_POST(): ")
        self.header()
        self.logInit()
        self.parse(self.path)

    def parse(self, path):
        parts = path.split("/")
        if len(parts) < 2:
            return
        command = parts[1]
        params = parts[2:]
        self.delegate(command, params)

    def delegate(self, command, params):
        pass

    def logInit(self):
        self.logJson = False
        self.logVerbose = False
        self.logAlertsOnly = False
        self.logColor = self.DEFAULT_LOG_COLOR
        self.logSize = "medium"
        self.logAlerts = []

    def logStart(self, refresh=False):
        if self.logJson:
            self.wfile.write(bytes("[\n", "utf-8"))
        else:
            if refresh:
                self.wfile.write(bytes("<html>\n<head><title>AirServer</title><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"{}\"></head>\n".format(self.REFRESH_RATE), "utf-8"))
            else:
                self.wfile.write(bytes("<html>\n<head><title>AirServer</title></head>\n", "utf-8"))
            self.wfile.write(bytes("<body style=\"font-family:'Lucida Console','Courier New',monospace;font-size:{};background-color:#234;color:{};\">\n".format(self.logSize, self.logColor), "utf-8"))

    def log(self, s):
        if self.logAlertsOnly and self.logColor != self.ALERT_LOG_COLOR:
            return
        if self.logJson:
            self.wfile.write(bytes("\t\"{}\",\n".format(s), "utf-8"))
        else:
            s = s.replace("\n", "<br/>\n").replace("\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;")
            self.wfile.write(bytes("<div style=\"font-size:{};color:{};\">{}</div>\n".format(self.logSize, self.logColor, s), "utf-8"))

    def logAlert(self, s):
        suppress = HttpHandler.items.get("server").getCurrent("suppress")
        if suppress is not None:
            suppress = suppress.split("~")
            for token in suppress:
                if token.lower() in s.lower():
                    return
        self.logColor = self.ALERT_LOG_COLOR
        self.logAlerts.append(s)
        self.log(s)
        self.logColor = self.DEFAULT_LOG_COLOR

    def logHighlight(self, s):
        self.logColor = "#fff"
        self.log(s)
        self.logColor = self.DEFAULT_LOG_COLOR

    def logCommand(self, s):
        self.logColor = "#8f8"
        self.log(s)
        self.logColor = self.DEFAULT_LOG_COLOR

    def logLink(self, link, text):
        self.log("<a href=\"{}\" style=\"color:#484\">{}</a>".format(link, text))

    def logFinish(self):
        if self.logJson:
            self.wfile.write(bytes("\t\"terminated\"\n]\n", "utf-8"))
        else:
            self.logCommand("Terminated")
            self.wfile.write(bytes("</body>\n</html>\n", "utf-8"))

    @staticmethod
    def start(ServerClass, hostname="localhost", port=60001):
        print("Start server...")
        server = HTTPServer((hostname, port), ServerClass)
        HttpServer.hostname = hostname
        HttpServer.port = port
        print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostname, port))
        try:
            server.serve_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
        server.server_close()
        print("Server stopped")

    @staticmethod
    def start_(ServerClass, hostname="localhost", port=60001):
        with HTTPServer((hostname, port), ServerClass) as server:
            print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostname, port))
            server.serve_forever()

if HttpHandler.items is None:
    print("Init data...")
    HttpHandler.items = itemtype.Items()
    serverItem = HttpHandler.items.get("server")
    serverItem.addSample(["type", "server", "event", "start"])
```

Raspberry Pi Pico client:

```
import utime
import urequests
from led import Led
from wlan import Wlan

SSID = "M7"
PASSWORD = "blah"
HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 60001

led = Led("LED", value=0)
wlan = Wlan(SSID, PASSWORD)

wlan.connect()
if wlan.isConnected():
    led.on()
    print("connected")

    u = "http://{}:{}".format(HOST, PORT)
    print(u)
    r = urequests.get(url=u)
    print(r.text)

    wlan.disconnect()
    led.off()
    print("disconnected")
```

wlan.py:

```
import network
import utime

class Wlan (object):

    NUM_CHECK_FOR_CONNECT= 64
    CHECK_CONNECT_DELAY = 0.2
    CHECK_DISCONNECT_DELAY = CHECK_CONNECT_DELAY

    ssid = None
    password = None
    country = None
    wlan = None

    def __init__(self, ssid, password, country="DE"):
        self.ssid = ssid
        self.password = password
        self.country = country

    def isConnected(self):
        return not (not self.wlan.isconnected() and self.wlan.status() >= 0) #todo

    def isDisconnected(self):
        return not self.wlan.isconnected()

    def connect(self):
        self.wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
        self.wlan.active(True)
        self.wlan.connect(self.ssid, self.password)
        for i in range(self.NUM_CHECK_FOR_CONNECT):
            if self.isConnected():
                break
            utime.sleep(self.CHECK_CONNECT_DELAY)
        return self.isConnected()

    def disconnect(self):
        self.wlan.disconnect()
        while not self.isDisconnected():
            utime.sleep(self.CHECK_DISCONNECT_DELAY)
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import machine
    led = machine.Pin("LED")
    led.off()

    wlan = Wlan("M7", "blah")
    print("connect...")
    wlan.connect()
    if wlan.isConnected():
        led.on()
        print("connected")
        wlan.disconnect()
        led.off()
        print("disconnected")
    else:
        print("failure")
```

Via a browser I got a response. On Raspberry Pi Pico I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 23, in <module>
  File "urequests.py", line 180, in get
  File "urequests.py", line 91, in request
OSError: [Errno 113] EHOSTUNREACH
```

Connection to WLAN works and firewall is off.

Answer (score 1):

Change `HOST = "localhost"` to `HOST = "0.0.0.0"` in server.py - it should make the server available in the home network, whereas `HOST = "localhost"` only makes it available on the same machine. Then get the server's ip in the network (on Linux it can be done with `ip addr` or any other similar command). Try using this ip as `HOST` in the client code